# File system preventing execution of files

Tags: filesystems

So I have a particular ext4 drive that doesn't allow me to execute files. I have the following example in bash where even with sudo and with the file having execute permissions for all users, the file does not execute. If I move the file to an alternate partition, it works fine. Thoughts?

```
$ ./pycharm.sh
bash: ./pycharm.sh: Permission denied
$ sudo ./pycharm.sh
sudo: unable to execute ./pycharm.sh: Permission denied
$ sudo -s
# ./pycharm.sh
bash: ./pycharm.sh: Permission denied
# lsattr pycharm.sh
-------------e-- pycharm.sh
# ls -la pycharm.sh 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 me me 5908 Nov 20 03:18 pycharm.sh
```

Comment: The [mount options](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) on linux default to  rw, suid, dev, **exec**, auto, nouser, async, and relatime. However it is possible to mount witht he reverse, e.g. 'noauto' for optical drives.

Please check if your volume is not mounted with no-exec.

Comment: @Hennes all my other drives don't have exec or noexec (must exec automatically) and they work. This drive doesn't and uses the same config: ext4 users,relatime,errors=remount-ro  0  1

Comment: Yup. The default (if not specified) is exec.  However it was worth checking for either this or for ACLs.

Comment: No ACLs present. The same thing happens to unrelated executables.

Comment: Does anything appear in logs (/var/log/messages, /var/log/secure) when you try to run the script?

Comment: What if you do a touch forcefsck in the root of the mount point for the filesystem and reboot, to do a check of it.

Comment: Also audit logs - `ausearch -m avc --start recent`

Comment: Thanks, I will try an fsck. It looks like this drive is showing some bad sectors, so wonder if this is related. And I didn't see anything with a tail of /var/log/*

Comment: Modern drives showing bad sectors is scary. Modern SATA drives (and older SCSI drives and recent SAS drives) all remap failed sectors to spares. They should only show bad sectors when they run out of spares.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have set your fstab options to prevent execution on this filesystem?

Have a look at /etc/fstab, maybe you've set the **noexec** option.

Comment: It doesn't appear so. They are the same as my other partitions: ext4 users,relatime,errors=remount-ro  0  1

Comment: What does the 'mount' command say? Perhaps there are errors that are forcing it to re-mount with restrictive options?